# How to reference dynamic file within {% static %} call?

Tags: python, django

Django newbie here getting started with my first app...

I need to reference an image within my static assets folder ([project]/static/images/____.jpg) and I've been doing so using the {% static %} template tag similarly to the example in the getting started tutorial:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/image.jpg" %}">
```

However, I need to reference the image file itself using a variable which is passed in from the view.py file. Of course, this syntax doesn't work but should illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
<img src="{% static "my_app/{{ imagevariable }}" %}">
```

What's the correct syntax for referencing this variable within the static template tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `with` a try: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

```
{% with "myapp/"|add:imagevariable as filename %}
  <img src="{% static filename %}">
{% endwith %}
```

You can also use get_static_prefix: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_static_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-get_static_prefix)

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}myapp/{{ imagevariable }}">
```

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick! Thanks for the link to the documentation. I get what's going on here.